# JQuery - check when window is at the top (user can not scroll up any more)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    $('.top_fixed').fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
});
```

I want to return opacity to 1 when window is at top (when user cann't scroll up any more). How can I make this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/eE9tp/

Behaviour: scroll down and when you will scroll to the top you will see `opacity` becoming `.7`

API: `scrollTop` - http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

This should help, `B-)`

**code**

```
 $scrtop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ($scrtop > 100) {
        $topnavbar.stop(true).fadeTo(500, 1);
    } else {
        $topnavbar.stop(true).fadeTo(500, .7);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    // means you cant scroll up anymore
}
```